# How to show match and unmatch SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get all records from two tables and add status match or mismatch. I try this code in MySQL but this code only show one record instead of all records

```sql
SELECT 
  id, source, destination, amount, CASE 
    WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN "MATCH" ELSE "MISMATCH" END AS "status" 
FROM 
  (
   SELECT 
    temporary1.id, temporary1.source, temporary1.destination, temporary1.amount
      FROM temporary1
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT temporary2.id, temporary2.source, temporary2.destination, temporary2.amount 
      FROM temporary2
   ) compare  ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

could you show where is my mistakes?

@EDIT
I'm sorry for not giving detail explanation.
I have two tables with same columns.
The column's names are `id`, `source`, and `destination`.

for example record in `temporary1` table

```
+----+--------+-------------+--------+
| id | source | destination | amount |
+----+--------+-------------+--------+
|  1 | Adam   | Helen       |    100 |
|  2 | Mai    | Dan         |    200 |
+----+--------+-------------+--------+
```

and from ```temporary1`` table is

```
+----+--------+-------------+--------+
| id | source | destination | amount |
+----+--------+-------------+--------+
|  1 | Adam   | Helen       |    100 |
|  2 | Marina | Daniel      |    400 |
+----+--------+-------------+--------+
```

The result from query should be like this

```
+----+--------+-------------+--------+----------+
| id | source | destination | amount |  status  |
+----+--------+-------------+--------+----------+
|  1 | Adam   | Helen       |    100 | MATCH    |
|  2 | Mai    | Dan         |    200 | MISMATCH |
|  2 | Marina | Daniel      |    400 | MISMATCH |
+----+--------+-------------+--------+----------+
```

`status` column's value will be `MATCH` if record from table `temporary1` and `temporary2` exists in both tables, otherwise result will me `MISMATCH`. When I run previous query, it give the same structure that I want. but only show 1 record.

Database is MySQL MariaDB ver 10.4.12.
I'm still new in database. I don't know much the difference between SQL database. So I thought all SQL database can run same query.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I'm sorry for not give detail explanation. I've updated the question. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to just need `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT id, source, destination, amount, 
       (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN "MATCH" ELSE "MISMATCH" END) AS "status" 
FROM ((SELECT temporary1.id, temporary1.source, temporary1.destination, temporary1.amount
       FROM temporary1
      ) UNION ALL 
      (SELECT temporary2.id, temporary2.source, temporary2.destination, temporary2.amount 
       FROM temporary2
      )
     ) compare 
GROUP BY id, source, destination, amount
ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add GROUP BY clause in your SQL since you are computing count(1).

sample SQL -

```
select id, source, destination, amount, CASE WHEN ccount > 1 THEN "MATCH" ELSE "MISMATCH" END AS "status" 
from (SELECT id, source, destination, amount, COUNT(*) as ccount 
FROM (SELECT temporary1.id, temporary1.source, temporary1.destination, temporary1.amount FROM temporary1
UNION ALL SELECT temporary2.id, temporary2.source, temporary2.destination, temporary2.amount 
FROM temporary2) 
group by id, source, destination, amount)
```

However I would recommend you to use INTERSECT, MINUS and UNION to get matched records and unmatched records.

Following SQL will return MATCHED records -

```
SELECT temporary1.id, temporary1.source, temporary1.destination, temporary1.amount, 'MATCHED' FROM temporary1
INTERSECT
SELECT temporary2.id, temporary2.source, temporary2.destination, temporary2.amount, 'MATCHED'
FROM temporary2;
```

Comment: The question appears to be about MySQL

Comment: thank you for your answer. but when I try to run your query, it gives me error. #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'group by id, source, destination, amount) LIMIT 0, 25' at line 6